# Regular expression to strip beginning and ending from certificate in Python

Tags: python, regex, ssl-certificate

Certificate contain the beginning and end like:

```html
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- [Base64 of certificate] -----END CERTIFICATE
```

I need to extract just the [Base64 of certificate] part, i.e., between the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- " and " -----END CERTIFICATE-----" strings. Can we have a regex for the same in **Python**.

This is my cerificate:

```html
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Use http://www.regex101.com to construct it using this as testdata ? Also, what code did you try and why does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----"""

m = re.search(r"(?<=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----).*?(?=-----END CERTIFICATE-----)", s, flags=re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print( m.group() )
```

**Output:**

```
    MIIBuTCCASKgAwIBAgIQNdNhtuV5GbNHYZsf+LvM0zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAb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```

Comment: Rakesh , perfect. how to get 'serial number' from this certificate using OpenSSL. "openssl x509 -serial -noout" can be used in cli. do we have any alternatives in python ?

Comment: @EbinDavis that's a totally separate question, and there is a very well-documented way to perform calls to the system from python and capture the output -- look at the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check if the line contains the BEGIN CERTIFICATE string and then iterate until you find the END CERTIFICATE string?

Comment: msg="".join([ line for line in s.splitlines() if "CERTIFICATE" not in line])

Answer (score 1):

Just use string slicing instead since these keys will always be the same length.

```
 >>>key = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
           MIIBuTCCASKgAwIBAgIQNdNhtuV5GbNHYZsf+LvM0zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAb
           MRkwFwYDVQQDExBFZGlkZXYgU21va2VUZXN0MB4XDTA4MTExMjE5NTEzNVoXDTM5
           MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQRWRpZGV2IFNtb2tlVGVzdDCBnzANBgkq
           hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAm6zGzqxejwswWTNLcSsa7P8xqODspX9VQBuq
           5W1RoTgQ0LNR64+7ywLjH8+wrb/lB6QV7s2SFUiWDeduVesvMJkWtZ5zzQyl3iUa
           CBpT4S5AaO3/wkYQSKdI108pXH7Aue0e/ZOwgEEX1N6OaPQn7AmAB4uq1h+ffw+r
           RKNHqnsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCZmj+pgRsN6HpoICawK3XXNAmi
           cgfQkailX9akIjD3xSCwEQx4nG6tZjTz30u4NoSffW7pch58SxuZQDqW5NsJcQNq
           Ngo/dMoqqpXdi2/0BYEcJ8pjsngrFm+fM2BnyGpXH7aWuKsWjVFGlWlF+yi8I35Q
           8wFJt2Z/XGA7WWDjvw==
           -----END CERTIFICATE-----"

>>>key[27:-25]
'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'
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner... so? The answer is still quite clear and concise imo.

Comment: I'd recommend just using triple quotes if you're gonna do multiline. Regardless, if the certificate lines are constant, this is a good answer.

Comment: Certificates can be longer than this though, run: `openssl s_client -showcerts google.com:443`